# How to calculate time intervals sub-setting by dates?

Tags: r, subset, difftime

Any help will be great.

I have a data.frame that looks like this one:

```
    Date       Time 
1  2015-06-30 14:30:00 
2  2015-06-30 14:35:00 
3  2015-06-30 14:40:00 
4  2015-07-03 00:25:00 
5  2015-07-03 03:27:00
```

And I would like to add a new column. In this new column, each row would have the time difference between the present row and the previous one, considering the date.

Ex:

```
   Date       Time     Diff (min)
1  2015-06-30 14:30:00 0      
2  2015-06-30 14:35:00 5 
3  2015-06-30 14:40:00 5
4  2015-07-03 00:25:00 0 
5  2015-07-03 03:27:00 182
```

The Diff for the first row for each date should be zero. The Diff does not need to be in minutes.

All examples that I found did not use the row approach to do the subtraction.

Any ideas how I could do this on R?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems fairly straightforward. Convert to a datetime column then use `ave` to apply `difftime` separately within each date. You should show where you are getting stuck in this process. All of these steps have been illustrated many times and I would be surprised if there were not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @rawr: wouldn't  paste0 coerce to character if they were something else?

Comment: @42- I was going to add the dput so I was waiting on an answer

Comment: I was sure that coercion would happen for a factor and just tested on a Date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step solution in a more R like way by avoiding loops.  The comments in the code should explain the logic.

```
df<-read.table(header=TRUE, sep= " ", 
text= "Date Time
2015-06-30 14:30:00
2015-06-30 14:35:00
2015-06-30 14:40:00
2015-07-03 00:25:00
2015-07-03 03:27:00")

#find time difference
delta<-diff(as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time)))

#determine if across different days by finding difference 
#if deltadays >0 then difference days and setting delta to 0
delta[diff(as.Date(df$Date)) >0]<-0

#add zero in front
delta<-c(0, delta)
#create desired dataframe
df<-cbind(df, diff=delta)
```

Since R does not have a time object (only a date or datetime objects) one needs to combine the date and time columns to calculate the differences.  There are ways to use a time object in R but that would involve adding additional packages such as `chron` but is this case it is just easier to create the datetime object on the fly for the calcuation.